# Extjs 4 + programatically add renderer during metachange

Tags: extjs, metadata

I have and Ext JS 4.2 grid that has to change based on the Metadata and all works well except when a column has a renderer. Is it even possible to have the renderer created at this time. Here is basically what I am trying to do

```
function metaChanged(store,meta){
    var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#mainItemGrid')[0];
    grid.reconfigure(store,meta.columns);
    var colPosition = 0;
    Ext.each(meta.columns,function(col){
       if (col.renderer !== undefined){
           switch(col.dataIndex){
               case 'chgflag':
                   var myCol = grid.columns[colPosition];
                   var f = function(value,metaData,record,rowIndex,colIndex,store,view){
                       return Ext.String.format("<img src='_images/{0}", record.data.chgflag); 
                   };
                   myCol.renderer = f;
                   break;
           }
       } 
       colPosition++;
    }, this);

}
```

I have only added one renderer type to the switch statement but there will be multiple types of renderers that I will need to create so yes, I know it looks a little silly to have only one case in a switch statement. any help would be greatly appreciated. I have also  tried having the reconfigure statement after the enumerations of the columns but no luck so far.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to pass new columns that would already contain the renderers to reconfigure call so that no additional logic would be needed?

Comment: the user selects the columns that they want from something like 116 available columns and then saves the layout. I drop the metadata from each column into a database table and then each user can recall whatevery saved layout that they want so I dont know exactly what columns they want to see.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I feel kind of stupid. Here is the final version and what I did to fix it.

```
function metaChanged(store,meta){
    var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#mainItemGrid')[0];    
    var colPosition = 0;
    Ext.each(meta.columns,function(col){
       if (col.renderer !== undefined){
           switch(col.dataIndex){
               case 'chgflag':
                   var f = function(value,metaData,record,rowIndex,colIndex,store,view){
                       return Ext.String.format("<img src='_images/{0}' height=15px width=15px />", record.data.chgflag); 
                   };
                   meta.columns[colPosition].renderer = f;
                   break;
               case 'rc':
                   var rc = function(value,metaData,record,rowIndex,colIndex,store,view){
                       return Ext.String.format("<img src='_images/{0}' height=15px width=15px />", record.data.rc); 
                   };
                   meta.columns[colPosition].renderer = rc;                   
                   break;                                      
           }

       } 
       colPosition++;
    }, this);
    grid.reconfigure(store,meta.columns);
```

Basically the column that I was using was a copy so the change that I was making was not affecting meta.columns. After I found that I was getting a bunch of css after the image becuase if you look closely you can see that I missed closing the img tag so I added the height and width and closed the tag. All is wonderful now.